# Selected on editing the data with pivot table values

Tags: php, laravel, select, eloquent

I have 3 tables,

```php
$student= Student::with('zones', 'appliances','phones')->findOrFail($id);
$appliances = Appliance::all('id', 'name');
```

I want to get the appliances field selected on editing student.

```php
public function phones()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Phone::class);
}

public function appliances()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Appliance::class, 'dealer_appliances');
}
```

I get collection when I `dd(user.appliances)`. How can I get these fields selected in select field on edit?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know If It is a good approach, but I solved this way:

```
{{ in_array($appliance->id, $data->appliances->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : ''}}
```